# Creating a Memory Consuming Application

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I want to write an application that consumes a lot of memory on a server to be able to show problems associated with memory pressure on a server.  I know C# fairly well, but I am curious what the most efficient method of causing an application to consume excessive amounts of memory in a controllable manner.  For example, I'd like to be able to pass a parameter that says to consume x MB of memory and have it consume somewhere close to that value.  Any thoughts on how I might do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depends really, performance can behave differently under different use of memory. Allocating one large chunck might have a different impact than allocating many small chunks. If you want a good test, you should test both. When allocating memory through the GC in C#, you  can't really controle the underlying memory that is being consumed. Allocating directly (call Marshall.Alloc...) would be one way to go.

Comment: You can always implement the ray-tracing algorithm and loads tons of geometry. That will consume memory fast and brutally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't the easiest way is just to create a byte array of the size you're interested in. To get very large allocations you may need to use more than one array using this technique.

Also if you're so inclinded you could p/invoke to [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887.aspx)

If you just need to an app you could also use [Testlimit](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Testlimit.zip) from sysinternals. This utility was used in Mark Russinovich's awesome [Pushing the Limits of Windows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx) series.

Comment: That was my first thought but then I second guessed whether it could really be that easy?

Comment: Yes you should be able to use `GC.GetTotalMemory` before an after the allocation to see the difference

Comment: There is a limit to what I can allocate without getting a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' doing this.  Trying to jump much over 1GB always results in an exception.  I could spin up multiple copies of the app to get my desired effect but if there is a work around for this to get a big memory allocation 4-8GB in size that would be the best thing.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what "memory pressure" you are looking for:

- boot.ini burnmemory option - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833721 to really restrict amount of available memory.
- create a program that simply allocates large amount of memory and actively touches it. This way you can see how your other program reacts to slowness in memory allocation/usage.
- allocate memory in the process you are interested to create pressure on address space (32-bit mostly).

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it could be creating an array of bytes. Convert your input value from MB to bytes and then allocate the array. If you want to try the stack allocation directly, you could use [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx).